# Register dynamic C# variables in Lua

Tags: c#, variables, dynamic, lua

I want to register dynamic C# variables in a Lua script engine.

I tried (example:) `luaVM["PlayerHealth"] = gameValues.PlayerHealth`. 
As expected, the variable is admittedly added to the global variable's table, but during Lua script runtime it keeps its initial value, e.g. 100. 
So I can only teach the engine the different game values once before executing the script.

But I want the engine to know the current `gameValues.PlayerHealth` value during script execution, as `PlayerHealth` naturally changes.

I could register a function that returns the current value, but it looks kinda awkward:

```
if (PlayerHealth() == 50) then ... end (looks stupid)
```

Instead of:

```
if (PlayerHealth == 50) then ... end (looks cool)
```

I do not really know what to search for, so help would be very much appreciated. Feel free to ask anything you need to know.

Comment: The global environment is a table in lua 5.1 so you can use whatever metadata tricks you want on that to do proxy lookups, etc. Similar tricks are possible using `_ENV` in lua 5.2 and 5.3.

Comment: It doesn't matter how your code looks as long as it is logically sound and manageable.

Comment: I passed the Lua object to another thread, which updates the variables like this:

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can pass the lua object to a background thread and refresh the variables from there:

```
    public void RefreshLuaVariables(Lua luaVM)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                luaVM["PlayerX"] = vsc.PlayerX;
                ...

                luaVM["TargetX"] = vsc.TargetX;
                ...

                luaVM["SystemDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               Print(e.Message);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);             
        }
    }
```

But this may lead to random crashes.